# Unable to show Top right corner Menu bar in Android Studio1.3.1

Tags: android, css

Please tell what to do if i want menu bar in top right corner of the activity bar .
And i am using Android Studio studio 1.3.1
And activity_main.xml design seleted options is Below:
Nexus4 LIght MainActivity 21;

My menu_main.xml file is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"tools:context=".MainActivity">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_red"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/red_string"/>
   <item
       android:id="@+id/menu_green"
       android:orderInCategory="2"
       app:showAsAction="never"
       android:title="@string/green_string"/>
   <item
       android:id="@+id/menu_yellow"
       android:orderInCategory="3"
       app:showAsAction="never"
       android:title="@string/yellow_string"/>
</group>
```

And my MainActivity.java File is:

```
package abcd.shravankr.basic;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    RelativeLayout main_view=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_red:
            if(item.isChecked())
                item.setChecked(false);
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            main_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_green:
            if(item.isChecked())
                item.setChecked(false);
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            main_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_yellow:
            if(item.isChecked())
                item.setChecked(false);
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            main_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
}
```

Please give me ten points so that i can insert image in it to understand problem more clearly.

Comment: I have changed themes many times . But No themes show three dotted menu bar options.

Comment: Try   app:showAsAction="always"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/overflow</item>
</style>
```

> **actionOverflowButtonStyle** is used to show the custom overflow menu icon.

**EDIT::**
1. Extend your activity class to AppCompactActivity
2. add tollbar to your xml layout file.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar           
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

3. In onCreate() Activity

> Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); 
>   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: use this as your style in styles.xml or can you provide your styles.xml file so that i can see it.

Comment: Lot of error showing in the code . That u have provided

Comment: Error:(8, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'colorAccent' with value '@color/colorAccent').

Comment: add some color code at the place of `@color/colorAccent`

Comment: plzz give me some example of the color code and Drawble/overflow . Because i am new in android studio

Comment: do you have colors.xml file in values folder

Comment: then create file named `colors.xml` in `values` folder and the below code
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#1545AB</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF092B74</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#ffffff</color>
</resources>`

Comment: Now i am getting this type of error.Error:(16, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:src' with value '@drawable/overflow').

Comment: now download a three dotted image of size 24X24, 36X36, 48X48, 72X72, 96X96 and add this image to each drawable folder and named it overflow.

Comment: give me link of this type of images

Comment: i am unable to find its on the google. thats why i am asking to u??

Comment: Is it okk                                                 <!-- drawable/dots-horizontal.xml -->
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path android:fillColor="#000" android:pathData="M16,12A2,2 0 0,1 18,10A2,2 0 0,1 20,12A2,2 0 0,1 18,14A2,2 0 0,1 16,12M10,12A2,2 0 0,1 12,10A2,2 0 0,1 14,12A2,2 0 0,1 12,14A2,2 0 0,1 10,12M4,12A2,2 0 0,1 6,10A2,2 0 0,1 8,12A2,2 0 0,1 6,14A2,2 0 0,1 4,12Z" />
</vector>

Comment: why are using vector image just use the png image

Comment: there are four images . And i have only one drawble folder . What to u mean by each drawable folder

Comment: drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi

<br/>If doesn't exist then create the folders.

Comment: In res directory i am creating folders but not created.. why  i am facing this problem.

Comment: go to project directory, you will se the folders there and add the images

Comment: Four folders has been created . But ldpi is showing different . And still there is no effect on menu icon bar. Its still blank

Comment: brothers, thats it i can do for you without seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks bro four give me yr precious time. Now I have done everything whatever u said to me . Now what to do next... i am still in confusion..

Comment: if it does not work. Just do one thing..Upload your code on GitHub and share with me i will check it by tomorrow.

Comment: https://github.com/happyshravan/Android This is my basic app . Please give me your username to share with u

Comment: deepak786 is my username on github

Comment: by the way, i have made some changes in the code and push the code on github under branch named Deepak.
Check it out and let me know.

Comment: Pllz Answer this ques.why there is problem in Onclick method. https://github.com/happyshravan/SQLite